# Android Appium: Find element ID of an error?

Tags: android

I am doing research in Appium for a few days and get stuck in getting ID.

For some elements which always appear on screen, there may have no problem to get the ID by iuautomatorviewer. However, for some elements which only appear on screen for error notification like an image below and I cannot get an ID of the red circle in the image

[image: I cannot get an ID of the red circle in this image]

Is there any way to get the ID of the red circle?

Thank you in advance!

P/s: I am using Meowchat for practicing only. Thank to Meowchat

Comment: Add `imporp.android. R`

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid you cannot, it just a componentDrawable of TextView, not a view .

if you really want to control it ,   use getCompoundDrawables  from EditText, it will help you .

or you can implement yourself Error Notification,make the red circle a view.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to find elements.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='com.minus.android:id/username']");
driver.sendKeys("Username you want to enter");
```

Comment: Is there any way to find the id or xpath of the red circle inside Textbox username Suman? I need it to detect if the input username is pass or fail. Thank for your help Suman

Comment: Try to inspect element in chrome to find element id or xpath. 
`chrome://inspect/#devices`